# Optional closure with Bool return type

Tags: swift, closures, optional-parameters

I have a method with an optional closure argument like this:

```
func when(_ name:String, state:State = .normal, closure:(() -> Bool)? = nil)
{
    ...
}
```

I call them like this:

```
when("I do something")
{
    if !self.doSomething() { return false }
    if !self.doSomethingElse() { return false }
    return true
}
```

This gives me a compile-time error:

> Error: cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type
>   'Bool'

What is going on here? Why does Swift sees a type () where Bool is expected?

Comment: @dhin's answer was right after all! I had some methods that missed the `-> Bool` return type.

Comment: try this cz your closure returns bool but not your function

Comment: @Ishika But my `when` method itself should not return anything, only the closure does.

Comment: Note that (as it turned out) your problem is completely unrelated to optional closures. The real problem is in the functions which you did *not* show. So the title is misleading and (even if *your* problem is solved) the Q&A is more or less useless for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function **self.doSomething()** and **self.doSomethingElse()** do not return a bool value

Instead of

`func doSomething() {
    return true
 }`

It should be like this

`func doSomething() -> Bool {
    return true
 }`